# eclipse server runtime republishes everytime i restart eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss, publish

I have a large application that takes a significant amount of time to publish on the JBoss server. Once this job is done, I can start/stop the server as many times I want. But the problem revolves round the fact that I have to republish every time I relaunch the eclipse even though the files are already present in the server, i.e. the state of the server is lost.

It would be of great help to know of any method that could relieve me from the overhead of publishing my application every time I start a new instance of eclipse and instead just start the server.

Comment: Hypothetically, how could the state of the server be "known" after Eclipse has been restarted?

Comment: There must be some file(s) that holds the publishing state of it. I just don't want to republish an application that is already published. Changing a file manually would be much easier than republishing the whole application.